# Importance of CRS in Getis-Ord Gi* hotspot analysis

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, coordinate-system, hot-spot

I have a question about the importance of the chosen CRS in a Getis-Ord Gi* hotspot analysis - I am running a hotspot analysis (using Zone of Indifference spatial relationship) on a quite restricted dataset around the Galapagos Islands (equator area) and had to change the (projected) CRS from World_Gall to NAD27_UTM_15N. Turns out the hotspot analysis is quite different from the first run to the second. I have read about how the Getis-Ord Gi* works but still am puzzled about how different the results are, especially as the cell area (1 x 1 degree grid) my data is in hasn't changed much. Can anyone explain to me why this is the case?

Comment: What projection did you change to? If it was geographic (lat/long) that would explain it. The UTM projection will be distance based (meters) whereas a geographic projection is somewhat nonsensical and would produce spurious results. I do not believe that ESRI's implementation of the statistic calculates great circle distance if lat/long is used but if so, this would be kilometers and not meters which could also account for differences.

Comment: The first projection used was World_Gall changing to NAD27_UTM_15N

Comment: Sorry, I missed this in my quick read. Cylindrical projection correct for global distortions whereas UTM is more of a localized projection with inherently less distortion within the zone. This very well could explain the differences. However, I would not expect large differences in the G* statistic so, I suspect that something may be going sideways in the software. You could use a different software to verify the results.

Comment: That is a very good point about the cylindrical vs localized projection though I wouldn't expect it to have that much of an impact in an area rather local and at the equator. Can you recommend a different software to try instead? I am only familiar with ArcGIS and QGIS but am not aware of a proper equivalent in the latter. Thanks!

Comment: I would have to say that R is the de facto standard for spatial statistics and there is an implementation of the local Gi* (localG function) in the spdep library. I honestly do not trust ArcGIS and have found numerous mistakes, and very poor guidance, in their implementations of various spatial statistics. If you must have a GUI there is CrimeStat 3, PASSaGE and Spatial Analysis in Macroecology. But I do not know how well these software are maintained.